# PowerShell - Iterate through JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have looked at many examples, but I cannot get my code to work. The structure of this JSON seems to be different than any others I've seen. I need to iterate through these results and get "id" and "legalName".

```
[
    "URL: https://myurl.com/rest/api",
    {
        "value":  [
                      {
                          "id":  271,
                          "client":  "@{id=245; clientCode=; clientName=}",
                          "dbaName":  null,
                          "federalEIN":  "",
                          "legalCode":  "01",
                          "legalName":  "Test1",
                          "naicsCode":  null,
                          "status":  "Active",
                          "links":  "    "
                      },
                      {
                          "id":  272,
                          "client":  "@{id=245; clientCode=; clientName=}",
                          "dbaName":  null,
                          "federalEIN":  "",
                          "legalCode":  "02",
                          "legalName":  "Test2",
                          "naicsCode":  null,
                          "status":  "Terminated",
                          "links":  "    "
                      }
                  ],
        "Count":  6
    }
]
```

I've tried lots of different code examples, but none of them have worked. This returns nothing. I can't seem to get down to the properties I need.

```
$var = Get-RestData("https://myurl.com/rest/api/") | ConvertTo-Json
$var["value"] | select id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet to convert from a JSON formatted string to a `PSCustomObject` with which you can iterate over.

```bsh
$json = @"
[
    "URL: https://myurl.com/rest/api",
    {
        "value":  [
                      {
                          "id":  271,
                          "client":  "@{id=245; clientCode=; clientName=}",
                          "dbaName":  null,
                          "federalEIN":  "",
                          "legalCode":  "01",
                          "legalName":  "Test1",
                          "naicsCode":  null,
                          "status":  "Active",
                          "links":  "    "
                      },
                      {
                          "id":  272,
                          "client":  "@{id=245; clientCode=; clientName=}",
                          "dbaName":  null,
                          "federalEIN":  "",
                          "legalCode":  "02",
                          "legalName":  "Test2",
                          "naicsCode":  null,
                          "status":  "Terminated",
                          "links":  "    "
                      }
                  ],
        "Count":  6
    }
]
"@
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.value } | Select id, legalName
```

which returns:

```
 id legalName
 -- ---------
271 Test1
272 Test2
```